# How to get highcharts scripts on only some pages

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I've got a rails app with a couple .js files that refuse to work together.  I want to try making the highcharts.js and it's modules to be page specific.  The problem is that since they're from a gem, I don't know how to locate them and put them in subfolders of app/assets/javascript.  Has anyone solved any similar problems befores?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use gem for that? You can grab highcharts files directly from http://www.highcharts.com/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to place the require statement in a folder and file specifically made for the controllers that would use the highcharts scripts.  I added javascript_include tags to reference the script files.